# How could I do an executable file in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody! I already have a project, and I want to know if there is a way to make an executable file instead of writing the roslaunch command in the terminal. Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220766/how-could-i-do-an-executable-file-in-ros?/) by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-11**:
What do you mean with 'make an executable file'?

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-12**:
I already have a launcher, I want to know if it is possible to make a file like "an .exe" on Windows, in order of let other people who know nothing about ROS neither Linux run my project (double click and thats it). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of such a characteristic in ROS, but maybe the easiest way to do it is simply with a bash script (or another kind of script) which runs the 'roslaunch' command in terminal. In my robot I have a launch file which is run automatically at the startup of the robot, and I'm doing it that way.

**EDIT**: I suggest you to take a look at this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/219594/roslaunch-as-executable/) where there is an example script which could be valid for you.

---

Originally posted by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) with karma: 258 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-12**:
I'm really interested in the way your bash works. I'll really appreciate if you can give me more information about it. Thank you so much.

**Comment by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) on 2015-11-13**:
Sure :) as I said, I want the .launch file to be launched with the boot of the robot, so in my `.bashrc` file I have this piece of code:

```
 TERMINAL = `tty`
 case $TERMINAL in
           "/dev/tty2") roslaunch YOURFILE.launch;
           sleep 2;;
 esac
```

**Comment by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) on 2015-11-13**:
As you can see, I look for the 'tty2' terminal, and then I launch my file. You can do it with any terminal, or If you just want to launch the file in any moment with the script, you don't need to look for a specific terminal, remember that I'm doing that way because I don't want to interact with it.

**Comment by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) on 2015-11-13**:
I'm running multiple launch files at the startup, and I need to be able to locate in which terminal are each one of them. That's why I'm using the tty "hack", to identify where they're running.

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-11-14**:
That is really useful for me, thank you very much.